# Show image when a ListBox contains no elements in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, dynamic, listbox, datatemplate, visibility

I want to show a list of items in a grid(in a listbox ofc) but if there are no items to show, I want to display in image instead of the listbox. The best way for this would be to create a Datateplate to determinate weather to show the listbox, or the image.

I would like to avoid setting the visibility of the image or the listbox in code.

Can this be done, and how? Or I have to use the method I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MVVM, you could add property `IsEmptyListVisibility` and bind to it your image `Visibility` property to control when it displayed:

```
 Visibility IsEmptyListVisibility
 {
      get
      {
           return (list.Count == 0) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
      }
 }
```

Also, call `NotifyPropertyChanged` when сollection are changed to keep all in consistence

```
 ObservableCollection<...> list
 {
      get { return _list; }
      set
      {
           _list = value;
           list.OnCollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
           {
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsEmptyListVisibility");
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Yes I know this, but I would like to avoid this if possible. But if nothing better comes up, I'll use this. Thanks though ;)

Comment: You can change `Visibility` to bool and use `Converters` if you like, but there is no standard mechanism to handle `Visibility` of elements in case of empty list.